# Setting LegendLabel in Mathematica ListPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I searched many times but could get a simple way to get my desired output. The problem is this:
In creating `ListPlot`, and using ```LegendLable`` like

```
LegendLabel -> Placed[Subscript[x, y] "for a=", Above]
```

why I am getting the output as "**for a= Subscript[x, y]**" and not "**Subscript[x, y] for a=** ".
What could be a simple solution for it? I tried "**ToString**" also like

```
Placed[Subscript[x, y]<>ToString[ "for a="], Above]
```

But no success.

Comment: `Placed[ToString[Subscript[x, y] // TraditionalForm ] <> 
  ToString["for a="], Above]`?

Comment: `LegendLabel -> Placed[StringForm["`` for a=", Subscript[x, y]], Above]`

Comment: Many thanks, @cvgmt. It solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @BobHanlon. It also worked.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the inner expression:

```
Subscript[x, y] "for a="
```

Mathematica is going to interpret this as multiplication (the expression is syntactically incorrect as it stands, so Mathematica will default to considering juxtaposed expressions as representing a multiplication):

```
Subscript[x, y] "for a=" // FullForm
(* Times["for a=", Subscript[x, y]] *)
```

Mathematica has specific rules for how to normalize arithmetic expressions (i.e. how to order the arguments). What you want to do is choose a construct for placing expressions into a particular arrangement. There are many of these, but maybe the one you want is Row:

```
Row[{Subscript[x, y], "for a="}, " "]
```